# Limiting requests from the same source on DataSnap WebBroker Application

Tags: multithreading, rest, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, datasnap

I'm new to threads. So, I created an DataSnap WebBroker Application to handle REST requests from my Flutter App. The problem is, how do I block the requests after many repeated tries?

Already made research over web and forums, but I couldn't find the answer. I used Delphi 10.3 wizard to create this application, so the majority of the forums and possibly answers, uses alternatives that my project doesn't have.

When I spam requests (testing purpose), the Delphi application just freezes and get a lot of CPU related errors.

Comment: In production I tend to use a proxy or webserver in front to provide security, logging and traffic control. For example NGINX doing SSL termination of external connections, logging errors and rate limiting connections to backend servers.

Comment: In my case, it's just Delphi's web server running, there's no other web server or tool between user requests and data snap.